# Field theory: prove that $(\forall x \in \mathbb{F}_p : f(x) = g(x)) \iff f - g \in \mathbb{F}_p[X](X^p - X)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, prime-numbers

Let $p$ be a prime and $f, g \in \mathbb{F}_p [X]$. Prove: $(\forall x \in \mathbb{F}_p : f(x) = g(x)) \iff f - g \in \mathbb{F}_p[X](X^p - X)$.

I have proved the implication ($\implies$). However, for the other implications I am having struggles. Can anyone help me?

Comment: $\Longrightarrow$ is the harder implication.

Comment: Hint: show that every element of $\mathbb{F}_p$ is a root of $X^p - X$. Then, if $f-g$ is a multiple of $X^p-X$, every element of $\mathbb{F}_p$ will be a root of $f-g$.

Comment: @MattSamuel Then I probably did it wrong. I thought of that if $f(x) - g(x) = 0$, then clearly this is in $\mathbb{F}_p[X](X^p - X)$ as $0$ is in $\mathbb{F}_p[X](X^p - X)$. Or is this not true?

Comment: @hello They don't say that $f(x)-g(x)=0$ as *polynomials*, just that that is true for all values of $x$ in the field. In a field extension the difference may not be $0$.

Comment: @MattSamuel Oh yeah you're right. I'll think about another answer.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $f - g \in \mathbb{F}_p[X](X^p-X)$.Then $f(X) - g(X) = h(X)(X^p-X)$, for
some $h \in \mathbb{F}_p[X]$. But the polynomial function $X^p-X$ is identically $0$, then $f(x) = g(x)$, for all $x \in \mathbb{F}_p$

Comment: The polynomial isn’t identically zero, it is zero when evaluated on elements of $\mathbb F_p$

Comment: That is corrected. What I meant was the polynomial function.